# Component of Inno Setup that is an optional part of "full" installation type

Tags: inno-setup

I am using this code to install my program and the possibility of install ¨Extras¨ and install DirectX:

```
[types]

Name: "full"; Description: "{cm:FullInstallation}"
Name: "custom"; Description: "{cm:CustomInstallation}"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]

Name: "program"; Description: "{cm:ProgramFilesComponent}"; Types: full custom; \
    Flags: fixed
Name: "Extras"; Description: "{cm:ReadmeFileComponent}"
Name: "DirectX"; Description: "{cm:InstalarDirectX}"
```

The idea is that when you select to install DirectX, do not change the type of installation. That is, if the installation is full or custom, do not change that classification, if I choose to install DirectX. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, but this would be difficult to implement.

---

Alternatively, consider making "DirectX" a task, instead of a component.

```
[Tasks]
Name: directx; Description: "{cm:InstalarDirectX}"
```

---

If you want to have everything on one page, it's possible too. You can create a custom checkbox below the component list to serve a similar purpose as "tasks".

Comment: I wanted to try to use only the components (types + components) because I have defined the DirectX installation and others (vc_2013_x86 for example) from there.

Comment: I understand. But I do not have anything to respond to that.